# Is there a retention policy or time frame for data in the event tables _Send, _Bounce, _Open, and _Click

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

As the title says, I'm looking for some info on the data retention period for data in the event data views.  Are they subject to the 6 month default for data extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.  Each system data view will only allow you to retrieve up to six months' of data from all of the tables when utilizing Query Activities.  Link on those are below.  Thanks!

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/#shared